# Recommendation for chart library with image legend labels

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm not sure if Stackoverflow is the right place for my question, but I couldn't find a more suitable place within the [stackexchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology).

**My question:**
I'm developing a responsive website which needs to show some charts. There are [many great chart libraries](http://techslides.com/50-javascript-charting-and-graphics-libraries) out there but I could't find one which fits my special need:

Does anyone know a chart library which is capable of displaying a graphical image legend instead of a textual legend?

**Example:**
[image]

Instead of a text I want to display an image (like the smiley)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best regards
ninsky

Comment: When in doubt: [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic) and [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask) You might look at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com (but check their equivalents to those pages [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)).

Comment: It's possible to do http://jsfiddle.net/vrwjfg9z/2676/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took first one google showed me and it's possible to do with it:

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-legend-configuration

updated config with img and it worked

```
{
    value: 61,
    color: "#09355C",
    label: "Label 1 <img src='https://blog.codinghorror.com/content/images/uploads/2007/03/6a0120a85dcdae970b012877700749970c-pi.png'>"
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vrwjfg9z/2676/

Comment: Okay, funny to say that I've tested exactly the same jsfiddle, but did use the image path instead of the img tag. dohhh. Thanks man!